# How to write a regex that contains specific number of characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex that contains only abcde, max five characters and a character can occur max one time. I tried `[abcde]{1,5}` but `aa` or `bcb` are valid for this expression. I am not good with regex and I have done some research but I could not find a solution.

How can I write such a regex?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can do "max five characters" in regex, but not "a character can occur max one time". Try to solve the second part in java code.

Comment: you can do it without regexp are you obliged to do it with regExp

Comment: `"^(?:([abcde])(?!.*\\1)){1,5}$"`? This is a solved issue, I linked to the original answer (you just needed a slight modification since you have one letter more)

Comment: `^(?:([abcde])(?![abcde]*?\1)){1,5}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot. I could not find this question